# Gerar erro no final da cópia caso algum arquivo não seja copiado

Tags: windows, batch, cmd

Tenho o um batch que faz a cópia de alguns arquivos na rede, essa copia atualiza os arquivos anteriores pelos mais novos caso já existam no pasta de destino, porém se algum arquivo estiver em uso o sistema não apresenta a mensagem de erro no final apenas no momento que está tentando atualizar o arquivo.

No momento eu não quero resolver esse problema do arquivo estar em uso, eu só gostaria que o comando informasse apenas no final da cópia se houve erro na atualização de algum arquivo.

Eu coloquei no final a condição `if "%errorlevel%"=="0"` mas essa condição não funciona caso tenha ocorrido erros no meio da cópia.

Segue meu comando:

```
xcopy "C:\Origem\." "C:\Destino\" /c /d /e /h /i /k /r /y
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando o `XCopy`,e conforme [documentação](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx), é possível capturar os possíveis erros após a execução do comando:

> 0 = Os arquivos foram copiados sem erro.
>   1 = Nenhum arquivo foi encontrado para copiar.
>   2 = O usuário pressionou CTRL + C para terminar xcopy.
>   4 = Ocorreu um erro de inicialização. Não há espaço suficiente em memória ou disco, ou você inseriu um nome de unidade inválido ou uma sintaxe inválida na linha de comando.
>   5 = Ocorreu um erro de gravação do disco.

Fazendo alguns teste aqui, com todos os parâmetros que passou não retorna erro, pois por exemplo, o parâmetro `/c`, indica para ignorar error, logo não faz sentido ter, o parâmetro `/d`, indica para substituir arquivos por mais novos, mas como está passando o `/y`, para substituir se existir, também não faz sentido.

Logo seu comando ficaria:

```
xcopy "C:\Origem\." "C:\Destino\" /e /h /i /k /y /r
```

Ao realizar o comando acima, e um arquivo estiver sendo utilizado, retorna:

```
xcopy "C:\Origem\." "C:\Destino\" /e /h /i /k /y /r
C:\Destino\arquivo.exe
Violação de compartilhamento
```

E se ao realizar o comando:

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

Temos o retorno: `4`

Dessa forma pode fazer uma validação se o resultado do `ErrorLevel` for diferente de 4, quer dizer que algum arquivo não foi copiado, ou salvar a mensagem do `xcopy` em um arquivo de log, assim:

```
xcopy "C:\x\." "C:\a\bat\" /e /h /i /k /y /r > log.txt
```

Dessa forma terá os arquivos que não foram copiados nesse arquivo de log.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, votei como útil porém preciso resolver essa questão, ainda preciso que o comando continue a cópia caso ocorram erros, com esse comando ele não continua copiando, só preciso que informe no final se houve algum arquivo não copiado.

Answer (score 1):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Que tal implementar um looping para a ação de cópia?

Sugiro operar a cópia dos arquivos um por um isolando/suprimindo possível mensagem de erro e registrando se o arquivo não foi copiado no seu log.

Deixando para o final do looping a exibição do conteúdo do log para caso ocorra algum erro.

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_destino=C:\Destino" & set "_log_erro=%temp%\xCopyLog.log" & title .:^| *** Aguarde... *** ^|:.

set "_origem=C:\Origem" & cd /d "!_origem!" & type nul >"!_log_erro!" && echo/
for /f %%h in ('cmd /u /c set /p "=%_origem:"=%"^<nul^|find /c "\"')do set /a _t=%%~h

if !_t! geq 1 set /a "_td=!_t! + 2" && set "_scr_msg=Copias dos arquivos em andamento, favor aguardar^!!..."
set "_tokens=^delims^=^\^ ^tokens^=^%_td%*" && echo/f>"%temp%\_f.log"

echo/ & echo/Criando/atualizando arvore de pastas no destino^!!... 
robocopy "!_origem!" "!_destino!" /e /xf * >nul 2>nul & echo/ & echo/!_scr_msg!

for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%f in ('where /r .\ "*.*"')do for /f %_tokens% %%F in ('echo/%%~ff')do (
     set "_msg_er=<nul" & set "_msg_er=Arquivo em uso e/ou nao copiado: "%%f" "
     xcopy "%%~ff" "!_destino!\%%~F"  /c /h /r /v /y <"%temp%\_f.log" 2>nul >nul || echo/!_msg_er! >>"!_log_erro!"
     )

for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`find /V /C "^^^" ^< "!_log_erro!"`)do set "_err_cnt=%%a" & echo/
if !_err_cnt! geq 1 (echo/Total de arquivo^(s^) n copiado^(s^): !_err_cnt!) else (echo/Todos arquivos foram copiados^!!) 

echo/ & type "!_log_erro!"|findstr . | more & title <nul & type "!_log_erro!"| clip 
(del /q /f "!_log_erro!" & del /q /f "%temp%\_f.log") 2>nul >nul && timeout -1 & exit /b
```

---

**Obs.: 1)** Tem 1 espaço após o **`\`** no: **`delims=\`**

**Obs.: 2)** Cópia do conteúdo do log no seu ClipBoard (Ctrl+C)